# Route washer drain into toilet drain or vent stack?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, washing-machine

We have a house that has its washer drain into the bathtub drain through a pipe that was routed into the bathtub overflow pipe. It has been working fine but when the washer spews out its used water, it comes out with so much force that it fills the bathtub a little through the drain hole.

We would like to fix this outflow issue while keeping the location of the washer and its inflow hookups the same. One thought is connecting the washer outflow to the toilet drain or the only vent stack for the house. This is the topmostfloor of three levels.

Could you please share your thoughts on doing this or another better solution? Thank you in advance!

Attached pictures for reference and help, even though the plans are not accurate:

[image]

[image]

[image]